# Jquery - not value from input if exists on blur

Tags: jquery

If value exists in input field, on blur.. it should not remove the value.

But, here some logic from another function removes all my pre-populated value on fname, lname,id when blur from "ccNum" or "ccExpiry".

**HTML:**

```
<div class="right-container">
    <div class="guest-details">
        <input type="text" name="fname" disabled="disabled" class="form-control">
        <input type="email" name="email" disabled="disabled" class="form-control">
        <input type="text" name="id" disabled="disabled" class="form-control">
    </div>

    <div class="card-details">
        <input type="number" name="ccNum" class="form-control">
        <input type="text" name="ccExpiry" class="form-control">
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$('input[name="ccNum"] || input[name="ccExpiry"]').blur(function(){
    var text_value=$('input[name="fname"]').val();
     if(text_value!='') {
        alert(1);
     } else { 
        alert(2);
     }
});
```

Comment: And the question is?...

Comment: I don't see any input with the name "fname-pp"

Comment: $('input[name="ccNum"] || input[name="ccExpiry"]').blur.. should anyways be $('input[name="ccNum"], input[name="ccExpiry"]').blur

Comment: @EmanueleLeoni Sorry.. i added wrong name in script

Comment: @TDG ok, so your jquery selection is wrong. If you want to get both input elements and you've to use comma separator like this `$('input[name="ccNum"], input[name="ccExpiry"]').blur` Also I tryed your code and the disabled input remains populated